# How to choose which array to to perform an operation on depending on state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing something hideous to choose which array to map over depending on whether shownAppointmens is of length 0 or not.

```
 {shownAppointments.length
        ? shownAppointments
            .flat()
            .map((appointment) => (
              <AppointmentCard
                appointment={appointment}
              />
            ))
        : blockedDates
            .flat()
            .map((appointment) => (
              <AppointmentCard
                appointment={appointment}
              />
            ))}
```

I wonder if it's possible to simplify it, choosing either shownAppointments or blockedDates and not repeating the `flat()` and whatever comes after it. Something along the lines of

```
(shownAppointments ? shownAppointments : blockedDates).flat()
```

Comment: Yes you can, except that you forgot the `.length` in the condition:  `(shownAppointments.length ? shownAppointments : blockedDates).flat().map(/*...*/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Example

You can separate the logic of which array to render into a separate constant, and use all the chaining methods you need on that constant.

```
const hasAppointments = !!shownAppointments.length;

const list = hasAppointments ? [...showAppointments] : [...blockedDates]

list
   .flat()
   .map((appointment) => (
       <AppointmentCard
         appointment={appointment}
       />
    ))
```

Comment: your first answer worked fine! This is what I did ----> const chosenArray = shownAppointments.length
    ? shownAppointments
    : appointments;

Comment: @uber Glad I could be of help. Could you mark the answer as correct, if it is so?